# Is Independent jeffreys prior different from independent reference prior?

Tags: bayesian, independence, prior, uninformative-prior, jeffreys-prior

I have a model involving two scalar parameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ and derived the Jeffreys prior for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ independently (so for, e.g. $\pi(\theta_1)$, setting in the normalisation constant eveything that concern $\theta_2$, which in my case is possible). Then I computed the independent reference prior for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ using the Theorem 2.1 (page 18) of [this dissertation](http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-12142007-153554/unrestricted/Dissertation_ETD.pdf).

I found that these two are different.

1. Is this possible ?
2. If it is the case, is there any intuitive explanations for that ?

Comment: In 1. are you asking if it's possible to have a reference prior that's not a Jeffreys' prior?

Comment: @glen_b. No. I am asking if the independent reference prior for $n$ scalar parameters can be different from taking  the product of the $n$ Jeffreys prior for each parameter independently (assuming it is possible).